# A function (download_report()) within a CodeIgniter Controller is working on local machine but not on server

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a function named `get_reports()` (that downloads an excel file) within a Controller named `Bulkexport`

Navigating to the URL `http://localhost/mycontroller/bulkexport/get_reports`
downloads an excel file.

I have the same code on the server but instead of downloading it navigates to https://example.com/mycontroller/bulkexport/get_reports

and the browser throws the following error:

> This site can’t be reached The webpage at
>   https://www.example.com/mycontroller/bulkexport/get_reports might be
>   temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web
>   address. ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE"

This worked previously on a different server. Once I changed to a different server it is not working.

```php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

class Bulkexport extends Mycontroller_Controller {
............
.......

public function get_reports(){

        $id = $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id;
.............
..........
....

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('batches');
        $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        /*---------------------------------------------------creating file-----------------------------------*/
        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        $filename = 'Reports';
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'. $filename .'.xlsx"'); 
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $writer->save('php://output'); // download file 
    }
}
```

Comment: check your server error log.you could see the error..

Comment: Also check .htaccess is there or not..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure these extensions are installed in server (php_gd2, php_xml and php_zip)

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
sudo apt-get install php-gd
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

This will install latest version. You can can configure it depend on your PHP version.

For examaple sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd (If your php version is 5.6)

Comment: Accept or Upvote if its correct answer.It would help other developers too..Also keep mind that always check Apache error log to fetch these kind of errors. cat /var/log/apache2/error.log (For Ubuntu OS)